# Calling functions outside functions

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
std::string* f()
{
  cout << "1";
  return new string("5");
}
std::string a = *f();
std::string b = a.append("2");

int main()
{
  cout << b;
  return 0;
}
```

This code runs and return `152`

How is possible? If compiler is calculating value of its return string at compile time then how come I see `1` when running the code? And if this is done at run time, then I am never calling f() at run time, so I shouldn't see the `1` in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> If compiler is calculating value of its return string at compile time

That is not correct. A compiler can calculate some expressions at compile time but not all expressions. In this case, it can only be computed at run time.

```
cout << "1";
```

is executed when you call `f()` to initialize `a` with the line

```
std::string a = *f();
```

This happens at run time. not at compile time.

`b` is initialized using the value of `a` with the line

```
std::string b = a.append("2");
```

This also happens at run time, not at compile time.

Comment: But I am never calling f() at runtime... How is the `cout << 1` being called

Comment: OK I'm confused, yes a calls f() but a.append("2") doesn't and b is just that

Comment: The order of initialization is given by the order of your declarations*. `a` is initialized by `*f()` first, and then `b` is initialized by using `a`'s value. This is the same as if you had declared them in a local block. (*so long as you are in the same source code file.)

Answer (score -1):

Your example code prints "1" when global variable a is initialzed with "5", and then after global variable b is initialized with "52", that is when main() runs. So the complete output is "1" followed by "52".

Note that function f() is indeed called, not from main() but by the initializer for global variable a.

Comment: But this makes the function call happen at runtime... Aren't  the initializations happening at compile time and results written in binary? So how is cout being called?

Comment: You keep assuming that something special is happening at compile time. Nothing is. All the initializations are happening at _runtime_.

Comment: No, the initializer expression for a is not a const expression; it contains a function call (with a side effect) so cannot be determined at compile time. So initializer for a *must* be determined at runtime.